# Нарисовать букву N средствами svg

Tags: svg

Нарисовать букву N средствами svg

```html
<svg>
  <polyline stroke='red' stroke-width='3' points='40,80 40,40 60,80 80,40' fill='none'/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<svg>
  <polyline stroke='red' stroke-width='3' points='40,80 40,40 60,80 60,40' fill='none'/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
html, body, svg {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: .125;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-0.125 -0.125 1.25 2.25">
  <path d="M 0 2 v -2 l 1 2 v -2" />
</svg>
```